# Angular 2 routes resolve different component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Here is my use case:

When i load url /product/123 i want to load component ProductComponent

This is my setup:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([            
        {
            path: 'product/:productId',
            component: ProductComponent
        },
        {
            path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent
        },
    ]),
```

Now I have added a resolver to check if that product id exists, so my setup looks like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([            
        {
            path: 'product/:productId',
            component: ProductComponent,
            resolver: {
                productResolver: ProductResolver
            }
        },
        {
            path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent
        },
    ]),
```

My resolver checks if that productId parameter exists via api call. The problem i have is that when productId is not found I want to load NotFoundComponent rather than redirecting to different page (i dont want to change url like angular 2 documentation suggests).

Anyone knows how to do that? if not productId found via resolver load NotFoundComponent without changing url/navigate?

Comment: Please don't use the **angularjs** tag for questions regarding angular 2+, if you read the description of the tag it states _Use for questions about AngularJS, the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the "angular" tag._

Comment: Can you show your code for the resolver? What do you do when you determine the ID is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you want to do is skip the location change when you navigate to your `NotFoundComponent`.  I'm assuming you've injected the `Router` into your resolver and are doing something like this when the ID does not exist:

```
router.navigate(['someUrl']);
```

Or you might be using the `navigateByUrl` method. Either way, you can tell the router [not to change the URL](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigate-anchor):

```
router.navigate(['someUrl'], {skipLocationChange: true});
```

Comment: This is genius! Exactly what I needed, no need to use ngIf anywhere. Just delegating all the logic to the NotFoundComponent without changing url.

Answer (score 3):

Don't see why you'd need to load your component via router settings, I'd put it inside the Component that tries to fetch it from the service, and then if it doesn't get a result back toggle some boolean that controls whether the NotFoundComponent gets shown.  Some pseudo-ish code below:

```
ngOnInit(){
    if (this.route.snapshot.params && this.route.snapshot.params['id']){
          myService.getTheThingById((success)=>{
                this.isFound = true;
                },(err)=> {
                      this.isFound = false;
          });
}
```

Then assuming your NotFoundComponent has a selector in it like 'not-found-component' throw it in the template for the component that's calling the service.

```
 <not-found-component *ngIf='!isFound'></not-found-component>
```

Comment: This approach was actually I have chosen later but i had a lot of problems with it. I had to implement loading variable and isFound in the template to avoid view rendering to quickly. Also dont forget that if you have a lot of components with different routes every single one would have to have this line <not-found-component *ngIf="!isFound"> which is a problematic and does not scale well. Sunil D. has the answer I was looking for and its so simple!

Answer (score 0):

I once faced this problem.

What I did was, in the component, to create 2 other components (in your case, you have ProductComponent, NotFoundComponent, and the other one you want to navigate to, let's say ArticleComponent)

Then I inserted 2 of the components in the main one :

**product.component.html**

```
<app-notFound></app-notFound>
<app-article></app-article>
```

After that, in your `ngOnInit`, you see if the parameter is there. If he is, then you log it in a property, let's say `isParam = true`.

Your template becomes

```
<app-notFound *ngIf="!isParam"></app-notFound>
<app-article *ngIf="isParam"></app-article>
```

It may not be the best solution out there, but it worked for me !

Comment: This approach was actually I have chosen later but i had a lot of problems with it. I had to implement loading variable and isFound in the template to avoid view rendering to quickly. Also dont forget that if you have a lot of components with different routes every single one would have to have this line <not-found-component *ngIf="!isFound"> which is a problematic and does not scale well. Sunil D. has the answer I was looking for and its so simple!